# passing api data through react csv

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, redux

I am using react csv for generating excel file.

I got a sample data downloaded but to download the JSON data, I am not sure how to pass the JSON files from `RecipeReviewCardList` file to `tab-demo.js` file.

Can you tell me how to pass the data providing my code changes and sandbox below ?

This will help me to learn more and fix the issues by myself in future.
https://codesandbox.io/s/ko1q2x233

**tab-demo.js**

```
<div>
    230 sports | test Export Excel | Export PDF
    <CSVLink data={csvData}>Download me</CSVLink>;
    <CSVDownload data={csvData} target="_blank" />;
</div>
```

**RecipeReviewCardList.js**

```
 getCommentsData() {
    let comments = [];
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        comments = json;
        // comments = comments.slice(0,3);
        this.setState({ comments: comments });
        this.setState({ activeComments: comments.slice(0, 10) });
        //console.log(comments);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code Sandbox (based on yours) with a solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/81v8p8kmy9

In your code is much bad "React styling", but according the question:

*div* section is moved from **tab-demo.js** to **RecipeReviewCardList.js**

```
    return this.state.comments.length > 0 ? (
      <div>
        <div>
          230 sports | test Export Excel | Export PDF
          <CSVLink data={this.state.csv}>Download me</CSVLink>;
          <CSVDownload data={this.state.csv} target="_blank" />;
        </div>
        {listView}
        <br />
        ...
```

function **getCommentsData** now look like this:

```
  getCommentsData() {
    let comments = [];
    let csv = [];
    let csvTitle = ["postId", "id", "name", "email", "body"];

    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        csv = json.map(item => [
          item.postId,
          item.id,
          item.name,
          item.email,
          item.body
        ]);
        csv.unshift(csvTitle);

        comments = json;
        this.setState({ csv, comments, activeComments: comments.slice(0, 10) });
      });
  }
```

And, of course, **csv** is added to states.

I hope these will be helpful.